# When i run open my heroku app i got this meessage?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am hosting an API on heroku. When i try to run that i get this error message

2020-09-29T09:12:10.860262+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2020-09-29T09:12:10.866747+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling because quota is exhausted
2020-09-29T09:12:11.906319+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2020-09-29T09:12:11.997631+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143

I do not know why can you please help me?

My procfile is:web:node ./index.js

Comment: How does you package.json looks like ?

Comment: Could you be more specific with what's happening? Does the site run at all? Btw, if you have `"main"` set in your package.json, you don't need a procfile

Comment: You've used up all your free dyno hours for the month. You can view your free dyno usage here: https://dashboard.heroku.com/account/billing

Answer (score 1):

The cause is in the error log: `Idling because quota is exhausted`

In the `Free plan` you are entitled to 550 hrs free, which can become 1000hrs if you register a valid credit card. See [Heroku reference](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#usage)

Adding a CreditCard it would allow to run your app without downtime.